# How to get data exist for more than one instance which belongs to the same key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, informix

If i have table structure like that:

```
req_serial  req_year  emp_num  name
   15        2014      673     Jo
   16        2015      673     Jo
   17        2014      785     Noha
   17        2015      785     Noha
   17        2014      634     Reem
   17        2015      634     Reem
   18        2014      358     Moh
   18        2014      34      Amr
   18        2015      34      Amr
```

---

How to get the following result :

```
17
18
```

---

I want to get the `req_serial` if the same employee exist in more than one `req_year` belongs to the same `req_serial`? .How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `GROUP BY` should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT req_serial  
FROM mytable
GROUP BY req_serial, name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT req_year) > 1
```

If the same pair of values for `req_serial, name` spans over more than one year, then the above query returns this exact pair. We only need `req_serial`, this is why `DISTINCT req_serial` is used in the `SELECT` clause.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d4ea2/2)

Comment: Probably better to group on `emp_num` than `name`.